# Populate table with JSON coming from C# DataSet

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have my JSON serialized with Newtonsoft.Json dll but somehow I'm not being able to populate it properly.

The json variable `data` has the result of the serialization, and in `data.d` I have the objet I'm behind. It looks like this

```
{
  "Table": [
      {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"     
      } //etc, more objects
  ]
}
```

and so on ajax success I do this:

```
success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d); //result printed above                                
            $('#myTable').bootstrapTable({
                data: data.d.Table
            });            
        },
```

And it's not working, `d.Table` says undefined. However, if at chrome's console I create a variable `data` with the information coming from `data.d` and then `$('#myTable').bootstrapTable({data: data.Table});` it works.

Besides the weirdness of what's going on, I guess I could get rid of the `Table` objet in `C#` and send the actual data objet with its arrays back to ajax, but I wouldn't know how to do that in C# honestly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `d.Table` does not reference a valid object, which is why it is returning as undefined.  It should be `data.d.Table`.

```
success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d); //result printed above                                
            $('#myTable').bootstrapTable({
                data: data.d.Table
            });            
        },
```

Alternatively, you can declare a variable to hold the table data, i.e. `var tableData = data.d.Table;`.  Then reference that variable instead when populating the table.

Comment: I'll update my question, forgot to mention that `data: data.d.Table` also throws undefined. Weird.

Comment: @DanielSh. What does console.log(data.d.Table) show?

Comment: `console.log(data.d)` throws the objet starting with `Table` and `console.log(data.d.Table)` throws undefined.

Comment: @DanielSh. What about `console.log(data["d"], data["d"]["Table"]);`?

Comment: First the objet Table and the data and then undefined, something like `...  ]
} undefined`

Comment: Yes, it's pretty straight forward hence my astonishment at the `undefined`. I will do a quick check.

Comment: @DanielSh. Since you're using Chrome, checkout the Network tab in the Developer Tools and see what the actual response is that is being returned through Ajax (XHR)

Comment: This is the start of the response `{"d":"{\r\n  \"Table\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"key1\":...` Do you see anything out of place? Let me know if you need the whole thing.

Comment: It's not an actual JSON object, it's a string. It works when you manually declare the object because it is no longer a string.

Comment: I parsed it, then access to `.Table` was possible. Thank you Rob!

Comment: You're welcome.  It's always best to get to the raw data whenever you encounter issues like this for this reason.